# Woocommerce how to exclude the child pages (endpoints) of myaccount from the template redirect hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The login-register form has to be shown only like popup, so I've made redirect, to avoid default myaccount page for not logged users.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wish_custom_redirect' );
function wish_custom_redirect() {
  global $wp;
  if (!is_user_logged_in() &&  is_page('my-account') ) {
    wp_redirect( '/' );
    exit;
  }
}
```

To view their account page users have to log in or register in popup form.
But there is a problem - /my-account/lost-password/, my-account/reset-password/ are children-endpoints of myaccount. They have not to make redirect for non-logged users.
I tried to make like that

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wish_custom_redirect' );
function wish_custom_redirect() {
  global $wp;
  if (!is_user_logged_in() &&  is_page('my-account') &&  !is_page('my-account/lost-password/')  ) {
    wp_redirect( '/' );
    exit;
  }
}
```

But it still redirects. Maybe it's a bad solution at all and there's a better way? Or how to make this redirect correctly?

```
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');

function auto_redirect_after_logout(){

  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit();
}
```

To redirect only on logout helps, but doesn't avoid user to see the default page. They can logout, and then return on the prevous page /myaccount, and see that default register form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, you could use `is_wc_endpoint_url` function, or you could use `global $wp` and its property called `request` as well.

Since you've already tried `global $wp`, then I'll take the same approach.

Your code would be something like this:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wish_custom_redirect' );

function wish_custom_redirect() {
  global $wp;

  if (
        !is_user_logged_in() 
        &&
        ('my-account' == $wp->request)
        &&
        ('lost-password' != $wp->request)
     ) 
  {
    wp_safe_redirect( site_url() );
    exit;
  }

}
```

It's been tested on woocommerce `5.7` and works fine.

---

**Related Post:**

###### For redirecting custom endpoint on `my-account` page:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70395951/15040627